# 220vElectrical Nightmare

Tags: electrical

I recently lost the use of all of the 220v appliances in my house

The fan motor still comes on, but no condensing unit functions.
The light inside the dryer comes on, but no heat,
The oven light and stove top lights come on, but no heat at the burners.

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. There isn't enough information here for us to know what's going on, but even so I suspect that your best solution will be to hire a professional.

Comment: While as existing answers indicate, the problem may be in your house, it might also be outside.  Call your power company to check as well.  Also even if your main breaker doesn't look tripped turn it off and back on anyway, some older main breakers can half trip without any visual indication.

Comment: What other electrical functions have you lost?  Any outlets or 120V loads?

Answer (score 3):

One "leg" -- one of the two out-of-phase hot wires -- of the 220V supply is not being powered properly. You need to trace the circuits to find out what has gotten disconnected, or bring someone in who knows how to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Some services have fuses on each leg and one of these could have blown. The other possibility is a loose main at the panel this can cause electrical arcs and burn the wire off then professional help is usually needed. Don't try to use any 220 device or anything on a 120 circuit that may come on and off until the problem is found as this can make it worse. I am guessing you checked your breaker panel and there are no tripped breakers. Some older split buss panels that feed a 220/240 section could cause this if the handle ties on the breaker were removed, rare but something to check.